# Sorry, we are unable to generate a view of the document at this time showing by google document viewer

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am using google document viewer to view pdf and doc type document dynamically. It is showing pdf document correctly. But when I am trying to view doc type document specially this document. "https://digitallegalsafe.com/encrypted_doc/dec_13716545881Amar_cv.doc" it is not showing. It is giving error "Sorry, we are unable to generate a view of the document at this time showing by google document viewer". I have encounter this error several time but not get any solid solution or answer. Does anyone have any idea about this.

I am using this code to view.

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/gview?url=https://digitallegalsafe.com/encrypted_doc/dec_13716545881Amar_cv.doc&embedded=true" style="width:900px; height:600px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: You may be more successful asking Google directly. The Google Docs Viewer is a black box to most of us, we don't know what it does or what may go wrong with it.

Comment: I have search their forum too. but not get any luck.

Comment: "encrypted_doc"? doesn't sound particularly promising for google to be able to view it without a decrypt key.

Comment: No I have already decrypt it before showing it in google

Answer (score 0):

It is getting downloaded.
use this link https://docs.google.com/viewer

and add the full address of the file. Then add the `iframe` link into your webpage.

I too had the same problem but it is working fine for me now. See mine: http://microlabz.in/MyResume.php

Comment: No its not working for me. I see that you are opening a pdf document pdf also working here too, but not able to show doc file.

Comment: oh yes.. you should try a pdf. doc will create problems

Answer (score -1):

you set MIME Types of server. Ex: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document for Extension(s): docx
When docx will showed on website of your